# why the below code is running on pycharm but not on jupyter?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

```
import sys

list1 = [1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 5, 6, 1, 8, 9, 10, 11, "sddvdfvdfv", "feefegrge"]


def splitlist(list1, s):
    list2 = []
    l = []
    li = iter(list1)
    for _ in range(len(list1)):
        l = []

        for i in range(s):

            try:
                p = next(li)
            except Exception:
                print("Original List >>")
                print(list1)
                print("Smaller list >>")
                list2.append(l)
                for k in list2:
                    print(k, end="\t")
                sys.exit()
            else:
                l.append(p)
        list2.append(l)


while True:
    s = int(input("Enter size for smaller lists>>"))
    if s <= len(list1) or s == 1:
        splitlist(list1, s)
        break
```

the above code is running properly on pycharm but not on jupyter some error is coming.
Kindly tell why it is happening.
attaching the error that is showing on jupyter.
[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the whole stack trace, and not as a picture?

Comment: @Christian sorry I am not able to add the error here